# How to set a do-nothing handler to a by-name parameter?

Tags: scala, pass-by-name

I defined a method `treeNode` to create a node, and which can have children nodes. The simplified code is:

```
def treeNode(text:String) (children: => Any) {
    val b = new TreeNode(text)
    children
}
```

When I use this method, I have to write:

```
treeNode("aaa") {
    treeNode("bbb") {}
    treeNode("ccc") {}
}
```

You can see the leaf nodes they don't have children, but they have to have a empty block `{}`.

Is there any way to give the parameter `children: => Any` a default do-nothing value, that I can write the code as:

```
treeNode("aaa") {
    treeNode("bbb")
    treeNode("ccc")
}
```

Help~

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is *not* that you can't give it a do-nothing (default) value; the problem is that even if you do, functions with multiple parameter blocks have to at *least* have parentheses or braces for each block.

There is one exception: an *implicit* parameter block does not need to be referenced at all.  Unfortunately, you're not allowed to have call-by-name implicit parameters, and even if you were, your signature would allow any random implicit to work in that spot!

Now, there is a way around this, which I will show for completeness, but I suggest that (assuming you don't just want another name, like `leafNode`) you just leave the trailing `{}` there.

You can get exactly the syntax that you want if you do the following.  First, you need an implicit parameter, but you make it a wrapper class (could use `Function0` which already exists, but then the next step might have unintended consequences):

```
trait AnyByName { def eval: Any }
def treeNode(text: String)(implicit children: AnyByName) = (text,children.eval)
```

Now you need two things--you need to be able to convert a by-name `Any` into your new trait, and you need to have an implicit do-nothing one available.  So we

```
implicit val nameForDoingNothing = new AnyByName { def eval = () }
implicit def wrap_any_by_name(a: => Any) = new AnyByName { def eval = a }
```

And now we recover the behavior that you were after:

```
scala> treeNode("Hi")
res1: (String, Any) = (Hi,())

scala> treeNode("Hi") { treeNode("there") }
res2: (String, Any) = (Hi,(there,()))
```

(in your example, you don't return anything; here I do, to show that it works.)

It's a lot of tooling just to avoid some `{}`s, though, which is why I'd suggest only doing this if you anticipate this to be a very heavily used DSL *and* that two names is unacceptable.  (Also, if you expect it to be very heavily used, `treeNode` is probably painfully long as a name; I'd suggest just `node`.)

Comment: I want to say thank you very very much! It will take me some time to understand and try, thank you!

Comment: Great solution... actually I didn't get too far DSL at this stage... probably that I'll find this kind of stuffs in next weeks

Answer (score 6):

AFAICT you won't be able to pass a kind-of empty block by default.

Btw, you could really simply partition the task based on your `treeNode` function by creating another one `def leaf(text:String) = treeNode(t) {}`